# WebStorm 8.0.4 FTP Connection Fails

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am having same issue reported before in PHPStorm, when connecting with FTP in WebStorm 8.0.4.

The error I get is: Could not list contents of the folder "ftp://real-meal.com/

Also tried Pasive and/or Compatibility modes. Working on Windows 8.1 x64. Sometime worked  FTP navigation in "Browse Remote Host" menu, but after some playing with options (but restored to original) itsn't working anymore.

Here is the Log File:

```
2014-10-04 20:45:09,933 [14500504]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - > PORT 10,0,0,200,248,211 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,132 [14500703]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 200 PORT command successful 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,132 [14500703]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - > MLSD 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,549 [14501120]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 150 Connecting to port 42907 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,566 [14501137]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=cdir;sizd=4096;modify=20141004194828;UNIX.mode=0710;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=12;unique=821gadc001; . 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=pdir;sizd=4096;modify=20141004194828;UNIX.mode=0710;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=12;unique=821gadc001; .. 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=121;modify=20140318193753;UNIX.mode=0600;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadd16c; .bash_history 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=18;modify=20130718131903;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc004; .bash_logout 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=191;modify=20060310001223;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc002; .bash_profile 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=175;modify=20120522224723;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc003; .bashrc 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=13;modify=20140318174336;UNIX.mode=0600;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc01c; .contactemail 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=12288;modify=20141004194947;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc01a; .cpanel 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=8;modify=20140318192944;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadd301; .dns 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=500;modify=20120227124653;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc005; .emacs 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20140227192104;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gae45f7; .fontconfig 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=126;modify=20131016034936;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc02d; .gemrc 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20131016034935;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc016; .htpasswds 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=121;modify=20130708103042;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc006; .kshrc 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=14;modify=20141004194828;UNIX.mode=0600;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc050; .lastlogin 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20141004023907;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gae8d73; .sqmailattach 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20141004024241;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gae8d70; .sqmaildata 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20131016070103;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc05b; .ssh 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20131016041317;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc057; .trash 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=658;modify=20120622230417;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc007; .zshrc 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=OS.unix=slink:;size=33;modify=20131016035124;UNIX.mode=0777;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc034; access-logs 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20131224001846;UNIX.mode=0750;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=12;unique=821gadc013; etc 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20140930083245;UNIX.mode=0751;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc015; mail 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=25807;modify=20140314180050;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadd304; malware.txt 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20131029174652;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gae8d46; perl5 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20131016034935;UNIX.mode=00;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc018; public_ftp 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20140729171458;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc009; public_html 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20140318221014;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gae405c; public_html.old 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20140327044247;UNIX.mode=0750;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gafcc60; ssl 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20141003081157;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc014; tmp 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=file;size=24106;modify=20120829210400;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc008; webalizer.conf 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,567 [14501138]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - type=OS.unix=slink:;size=11;modify=20131016034935;UNIX.mode=0777;UNIX.uid=2513;UNIX.gid=2508;unique=821gadc01d; www 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,568 [14501139]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 226-Options: -a -l 
226 32 matches total 
2014-10-04 20:45:10,571 [14501142]   WARN - i.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode - Could not list the contents of folder "ftp://74.220.207.154/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "ftp://74.220.207.154/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:926)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:443)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:1006)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:142)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:103)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeContext.getConnection(ServerTreeContext.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.computeFile(ServerTreeNode.java:266)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.getChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:132)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.SimpleTreeStructure.getChildElements(SimpleTreeStructure.java:25)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$31.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:1620)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1826)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.getChildrenFor(AbstractTreeUi.java:1617)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$4600(AbstractTreeUi.java:61)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$46.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:2704)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1826)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2400(AbstractTreeUi.java:61)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$57$1.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3382)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.WebServerTreeBuilder.runBackgroundLoading(WebServerTreeBuilder.java:90)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$57.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3373)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1826)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2400(AbstractTreeUi.java:61)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$58.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3438)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.MLSxEntryParser.parseFTPEntry(MLSxEntryParser.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.getFiles(FTPListParseEngine.java:257)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.getFiles(FTPListParseEngine.java:229)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPExtendedClient.mlistDir(FTPExtendedClient.java:28)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpJBHelper.listFiles(FtpJBHelper.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:141)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doListChildren(FtpFileObject.java:459)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:917)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: See if "Always use LIST command" option is available under "Advanced Options" of your deployment connection. If it is -- use it. I'm not sure .. but it looks like it cannot properly interpret results of MLSD command (sort of advanced version of LIST; has few variations in syntax (AFAIK)). Please also try again -- maybe it's just a temp glitch...

Comment: Thank you for answer! Doesn't exist any "Always use LIST command" menu or so in any place of this release. Yes, debugging log shows file listing of my directory.

Comment: *"Doesn't exist any "Always use LIST command" menu"* Then it was been added later -- please try v9 EAP build -- it should have it: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP

Comment: (1) PhpStorm 8.0.1 has the option "Always use LIST command" and using this works with my connection.
(2) Also tested WebStorm EAP 9, using "Always use LIST command" and also works.

As a bypass i will use PHPStorm. LazyOne, please add as an answer with this information to accept it! THKU!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try `Always use LIST command` option under "Advanced Option" of your deployment entry. Right now it looks like IDE cannot properly interpret results of `MLSD` command (sort of advanced version of `LIST`; has few variations in syntax (AFAIK)).

**P.S.**
This option is available in PhpStorm v8 or WebStorm v9 (currently at EAP stage),

Comment: I'm having a connection problem to a FTP server as well with Webstorm 9....where do i set the LIST setting? I didnt see Advanced Options when setting up my connection

Comment: @dougmays `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment` -- "Advanced options" button is there

Comment: Thanks! Tried with passive mode on and LIST selected and still got hung up. Trying again now with just passive mode. Never done FTP on Webstorm before, this frustrating

Comment: and also turn on passive mode

Comment: To this day with the most recent version of the editor this answer saved me.

Answer (score 16):

My IDE version is 9.0.2 and I had the same problem.

Use 'Passive mode' at `Tools->Deployment->configuration...->Advanced options...`.

It will solve that problem.

[image]