# Could not list the contents of folder in phpstorm latest version

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I have latest version of phpstorm, downloaded today. While uploading files to remote server i click on refresh icon in remote host, then phpstorm displays error
**could not list the contents of folder phpstorm**. How can i correct that ??

[image]

Comment: Collect detailed logs and look into them for possible hints: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198502/webstorm-8-0-4-ftp-connection-fails - does it help?

Answer (score 28):

Go to `Tools` -> `Deployment` -> `Configuration` -> `Advanced Options`. Check `Always use LIST command`.

Works like a magic!

Comment: Ftp connected, but files not listed.

Answer (score 20):

Go to Tools > Deployment > Configuration > Advanced Options and Select the Pasive mode option.

It worked out for me!

Answer (score 3):

For me was that for some reason the folder of the `Root path` was deleted. Check yours!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools > Deployment > Configuration > Connection > Advanced and select:

- Passive mode
- Compatible with old version of listining children
- Instead of MLSD

It worked out for me!

[Step by step image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Cz6.png)

Comment: That worked for me too! I was going to post an answer but then I found yours. You have my upvote

Answer (score 0):

for me nether of these settings worked. in my settings i didn't even have passive mode (intellij idea).

so what i did is, lookup the server directory with a php info file (uploaded it with another ftp tool, that was able to list the direcories: transmit) and then rebuild that path inside `tools / deployment / root path`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Similar to the other answer, you want to chec Use LIST Command > Instead of MLSD. The other option does not matter.